# Move to area in circle, then snap to a grid?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rounding

Beginner here.
I am trying to get this to find a random point inside a circle, go to that point but then snap to a grid.

I have been able to get a point inside the circle and move there, but I haven't been able to figure out any working methods.

This is the code to find and move to a point inside the circle.

```
private void RandomizePosition()
{
    double x = -0.5; // center of circle x
    double y = -0.5; // center of circle y

    this.transform.position = UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitCircle * 7; // this makes the circle
}
```

I have tired using `this.transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Round(x), Mathf.Round(y), 0.0f);` but I get the error **"cannot implicitly convert type double to float"** If anyone has any ideas please share, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Mathf.Round`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Round.html) takes a `float` as its argument and you are passing a `double` in it. The following should work:

```cs
this.transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Round((float)x), Mathf.Round((float)y), 0.0f);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `float` directly:

```
var x = -0.5f; // center of circle x
var y = -0.5f; // center of circle y
```